# How to get Node Json Database working in this script?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am using [node-json-db](https://github.com/Belphemur/node-json-db) for storing data in my Discord bot. The bot's purpose is to be a patient records system for roleplaying in FiveM (this is not important, but I thought it would clear thing up a little). I have this script:

```
    module.exports = {
    name: 'search',
    description: "Searches for patient info from database",
    execute(message, args, Discord){
        import { JsonDB } from 'node-json-db';
        import { Config } from 'node-json-db/dist/lib/JsonDBConfig'
        var db = new JsonDB(new Config(`pdb/${message.content.replace('search', '').json}`, true, false, '/'));

        db.push("/test1","super test");

    }
}
```

(This script is for testing)

I cannot get it to work, and I get a error: `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` as I am running the script. Where should I put these import statements? (I am using external files for commands, I have a main.js for the bot skeleton (logging in, getting commands etc.))

Comment: Is this ts or js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused because by default node.js sets file type as `commonjs` in `package.json`. in-order to use `import - export` you have to specify this in `package.json`.

`type: module`

but if you set this, you will have to convert all `module.exports` and `require` functions to `import-export`. In this case an easier fix would be

```
    const { JsonDB } = require('node-json-db');
    const { Config } = require('node-json-db/dist/lib/JsonDBConfig');

    module.exports = {
    name: 'search',
    description: "Searches for patient info from database",
    execute(message, args, Discord){
        var db = new JsonDB(new Config(`pdb/${message.content.replace('search', '').json}`, true, false, '/'));

        db.push("/test1","super test");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a different database that works.